# Posting to VK via python API stopped working

Tags: python, vk

Something broke about March 1-2 in my python function that posts to VK group.
I did it the following way:

```
session = vk.Session(access_token=page.access_token)
api = vk.API(session)
post_response = api.wall.post(message=message, owner_id='-' + page.page_id)
```

but now this last post() command returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 173, in __call__
    return self._api._session.make_request(self)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 67, in make_request
    response = self.send_api_request(method_request, captcha_response=captcha_response)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 115, in send_api_request
    response = self.requests_session.post(url, method_args, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 518, in post
    """
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/utils.py", line 78, in request
    response = super(LoggingSession, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    the server's TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it must be a path
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    """
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    r,
SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

And I get exactly the same mistake if I want to get upload server:

```
>>> upload_server = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=page.page_id)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 173, in __call__
    return self._api._session.make_request(self)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 67, in make_request
    response = self.send_api_request(method_request, captcha_response=captcha_response)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/api.py", line 115, in send_api_request
    response = self.requests_session.post(url, method_args, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 518, in post
    """
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vk/utils.py", line 78, in request
    response = super(LoggingSession, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    the server's TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it must be a path
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    """
  File "/home/admin/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    r,
SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm using the latest version of vk package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vk , but it is a 1 year old now).

The only change in VK API that I found - https://vk.com/dev/version_update - says that now I must specify the API version; but when I replace `api = vk.API(session)` by `api = vk.API(session, v='5.54')`, nothing changes.

Maybe anybody have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: the problem isn't with `vk` but requests, try to do `pip install -U requests[security]` and see what happens after that

Comment: @aws_apprentice Great, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @aws_apprentice wrote, `pip install -U requests[security]` helped.
Then I still had to fix some problems with API:

1. replace `api = vk.API(session)` by `api = vk.API(session, v="5.54")` (you may want to use the latest version from `https://vk.com/dev/versions`)
2. In the result of `api.photos.getWallUploadServer` there is now the key `album_id` instead of `aid`
3. `api.photos.saveWallPhoto(...)[0]['id']` is now int, not string

These changes were enough for me. Looks like it works again!